# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended (Sorting query)?

Tags: oracle

The code I have attempted to run:

```
SELECT "SALES_ORDER_NUMBER", "SALES_ORDER_DATE" FROM "Sales Orders"
WHERE "SALES_ORDER_DATE" BETWEEN '05/09/2016' AND '12-12-2016'
ORDER BY "SALES_ORDER_NUMBER" ASC;

SELECT "LASTNAME", FROM "Sales Orders"
ORDER BY "LASTNAME" DESC; 

SELECT "SALES_ORDER_NUMBER","SALES_ORDER_DATE", "EMPLOYEE_LASTNAME", "DELIVERY_DUE_DATE", "DELIVERY_CHARGE" 
FROM "Sales Orders"
ORDER BY "EMPLOYEE_LASTNAME" DESC;
```

I am most likely missing something, can someone please help me out?

[image: Full error message is]

Comment: Show your complete error message

Comment: Attached the link to the complete error message :)

Comment: This exhibits the same underlying problem as other questions you have asked here. These are simple syntax errors which you should be able to spot for yourself. Compilers are unforgiving: they need us to follow the syntax exactly. Developing an eye for bloopers in our own code is a key programming skill. But here's a hint. Commas are used to separate sets of things: a comma followed by nothing is a syntax error in most programming languages.

Comment: I've only started doing SQL for the past three weeks for a database subject (please be forgiving on my silly questions), the original code I looked at had commas to separate the table column names so I assumed they had to be in the code?

Comment: Ponnarasu thanks! It still won't process the statement though.

Comment: I'm sure it would help if you learned to format your code/queries properly. New lines don't bite but they help find typos. As a rule of a thumb you should add a line break before each `FROM`, `WHERE`, `ORDER`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Sorting order may be:

```
ORDER BY "LASTNAME" DESC;
```

or

```
ORDER BY "LASTNAME" ASC;
```

but not:

```
ORDER BY "LASTNAME" DESC|ASC;
```

First an third query that you show does not have sorting statements at all, so sorting will be by `id`

Try for example:

```
SELECT "SALES_ORDER_NUMBER", "SALES_ORDER_DATE" FROM "Sales Orders"
WHERE "SALES_ORDER_DATE" BETWEEN '05/09/2016' AND '12-12-2016'
ORDER BY "SALES_ORDER_NUMBER" ASC;

SELECT "LASTNAME", FROM "Sales Orders"
ORDER BY "LASTNAME" DESC; 

SELECT "SALES_ORDER_NUMBER","SALES_ORDER_DATE", "EMPLOYEE_LASTNAME", "DELIVERY_DUE_DATE", "DELIVERY_CHARGE" 
FROM "Sales Orders"
ORDER BY "EMPLOYEE_LASTNAME" DESC;
```

Comment: I did try the suggestion but the same annoying error came up... :O

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the comma in

```
SELECT "LASTNAME", FROM "Sales Orders"
ORDER BY "LASTNAME" DESC;
```

as suggested by @APC. I believe this should read

```
SELECT "LASTNAME" FROM "Sales Orders"
ORDER BY "LASTNAME" DESC;
```